# Find specific node height in tree c++

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I am trying traverse over tree and check for specific (rel_name) and return his height, but my function traverse over "mother" branch and checks only fathers branch.
The result is that my program return exception() and core dumping.
how do I fix my function to not core dump and check mothers branch too?

```
string treeHeight(Person* root, string rel_name, int height){
   height++;
   if(root == nullptr) {  
       throw exception();
    }    
    else if(root->name == rel_name) return to_string(height);
    return treeHeight(root->father, rel_name, height);
    return treeHeight(root->mother, rel_name, height);
}
```

Comment: Your code starts from a root, and first it follows the father branches as deep as it can go.  Eventually by following the father branches it reaches a leaf node where the father is `nullptr` and it raises an exception as written in the program. You need to scan the full tree beneath the root, until you find the `rel_name`.

Comment: I dont know how to implement it

Comment: I would advise you to write some code which visits every node starting from the beginning of the root and it has the distance of that node with respect to the original root. If you can write this, your problem would be solved. Anyways, I wrote some code, if you want some help - https://pastebin.com/LCPKkpHX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone has already pointed out, but if your code reaches a leaf and goes a little bit further, according to your base case it would throw an exception and exit the program.

I revised your code a little bit:

```cpp
int treeHeight(Person* root, const string& rel_name){
    if(root == nullptr) {  
        return -1;
    }    
    else if(root->name == rel_name) return 0;

    int leftHeight = treeHeight(root->father, rel_name);
    int rightHeight = treeHeight(root->mother, rel_name);

    if (leftHeight == -1 && rightHeight == -1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return (leftHeight > rightHeight ? leftHeight : rightHeight) + 1;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your code , you are not allowing the code to go the mother node, its directly from the father node call and thus its not getting executed ahead.

Try this below :

```
string treeHeight(Person* root, string rel_name, int height){
   height++;
   if(root == nullptr) {  
       throw exception();
    }    
    else if(root->name == rel_name) return to_string(height);
    int person_height = treeHeight(root->father, rel_name, height);
    if(person_height!=0) return height;           ---------> You need to apply this check
    return treeHeight(root->mother, rel_name, height);
}
```

Comment: the `treeHeight` function does not return `int`. So, this line - `int person_height = treeHeight(root->father, rel_name, height);` in your code is a mistake.

Comment: I fixed returning state to int and still it returns "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'
  what():  std::exception
Aborted (core dumped)"